# Marionette Controller Function Declarations - Best Practices

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm writing a large scale marionette application, which is ran initially from a router / controller.

Here's my question -- is it good practice to include other functions in your controller that aren't meant for routes?

So say I have the following method:

```
index : function() {
   alert('test!');
}
```

is it consistent with best practices to be able to declare other functions in the controller not called when routes are initialized? Like so:

```
noRouteAssociated: function() {
     alert('test!');
}

index: function() {
     this.noRouteAssociated();
}
```

Obviously this is a simplified example, but I am trying to avoid putting large amounts of information or function declarations inside of methods only because they're associated with routers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The roles and responsibilities of controllers are best illustrated by @davidsulc in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699175/new-to-marionette-router-and-controller-config) and better yet his new [book](https://leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction).

Generally speaking, it's okay to include methods that aren't meant for routes, *if* they're controlling the workflow of your app. Event triggering is a good example, but if you want to change the appearance of something or retrieve data from a database, you should move these methods to a view or model, respectively. The block quote below is taken directly from [Marionette's controller documentation](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.controller.md#basic-use).

> The name Controller is bound to cause a bit of confusion, which is rather unfortunate. There was some discussion and debate about what to call this object, the idea that people would confuse this with an MVC style controller came up a number of times. In the end, we decided to call this a controller anyways, as the **typical use case is to control the workflow and process of an application and / or module.**
>
> But the truth is, this is a very generic, multi-purpose object that can **serve many different roles in many different scenarios.** We are always open to suggestions, with good reason and discussion, on renaming objects to be more descriptive, less confusing, etc. If you would like to suggest a different name, please do so in either the mailing list or the github issues list.